# How to pronounce Arthur Wehnelt's last name as in the term Wehnelt cylinder or Wehnelt lens?

Tags: person-names, scientific-language

A [Wehnelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehnelt_cylinder) lens, grid, cap, etc. is a standard component in an electron gun on may types of scientific instruments including electron microscopes. It is named after its inventor [Arthur Rudolph Berthold Wehnelt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Wehnelt).

I've been using the term for several decades and always mumble when I speak it out loud because I'm not sure how to pronounce it. (I speak only English).

Is it possible to use some simple phonetics guide to help me pronounce it close to correctly?

Right now I say something like *Vay-nault* am I at least close?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmEoO.png).  [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Wehnelt_cap.svg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Vaynault" seems to be the English/American way to pronounce it. The German one can be listened to here (click the speaker icon next to the German translation): https://www.dict.cc/?s=wehnelt

The machine pronunciation for Wehnelt is correct although the entire words are of somewhat arguable quality.

I'm not the best with IPA-signs but here's my try:

> ​[ve:nəlt]

Possible analogy to English words

> **W**ehnelt as a normal **v** as in **v**owel
>   W**eh**nelt as **e** in v**e**in (suggested by Cubic)
>   Weh**n**elt as **n** in **n**o
>   Wehn**e**lt as **a** in **a**  tree(undefined article)
>   Wehne**lt** as **-led** in pick**led** (more pronounce t-ish than d-ish)

Comment: Thanks very much for the speedy answer, I won't have to mumble it any more!

Comment: I think when it comes to the *eh* sound there's no real englisch approximation. You can try it like the *ay* in *may*, or as you used to do with your *Vay-Nault*

Comment: That is true, but I think the *ay* is too a-ish. Still, both a reasonable close approximations

Comment: The colloquial *[meh](https://www.dict.cc/?s=meh)* (boring) might be a good approximation for that *eh* sound.

Comment: The pronunciation by the woman (or is it a machine?) on your link is really bizarre. The stress should be on the second syllable of "Zylinder".

Comment: Unfortunately I realised too late that it's only spoken by machines, yet the pronounciation for Wehnelt is on point. The male version seems to have a french accent, as well...

Comment: You can approximate the “Weh” in “Wehnelt” as being kind of similar to the “ve” in “vein”.

Comment: The meh is rather short and closer to an a/ä sound than the e in eh.

Comment: @fdb: I think it's a machine and I fully agree the pronounciation is weird (particularly the Wehneltelektrode where "she" doesn't have the pronounciation help of the dash).

Comment: should be a long "e" [ve:nəlt]

Answer (score 3):

**Correct pronuncation**

As the records offered by Dict.cc are indeed something between disastrous and hilarious, here is a record with a real living German native speaker:

[How to pronounce "Wehneltzylinder" in German](https://www.podomatic.com/podcasts/chgeiselmann/episodes/2019-12-08T12_58_20-08_00)

**Notes on the t-z difficulty**

On trying several times I find that the word "Wehneltzylinder" is challenging because of the word boundary between *Wehnelt* and *Zylinder* with two plosive consonants t and z (German "z" being pronounced "ts"). So, standard pronuncation would merge the t and z; however, in very slow, over-precise pronunciation you might separate the words audibly.

Here is a record to demonstrate this:

[Word boundary challenge in Wehneltzylinder](https://www.podomatic.com/podcasts/chgeiselmann/episodes/2019-12-05T05_53_15-08_00)

In everyday practice it might be a good shortcut to pronounce it somewhat like

> Wehnel - Zylinder

(i.e. leaving out the t of Wehnelt, and relying solely on the "ts" sound provided by the "z")

**Bonus info**

Also, this second record shows how to pronounce "Arthur" in German (which is rather different from English).

Comment: @CarstenS  Done. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your extensive answer and audio demonstrations!